# CUPTI error when using tensorboard callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am currently using CPU to train the LSTM neural network. When i run the code

```
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))

filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.3f}"  # unique file name that will include the epoch and the validation acc for that epoch
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models/{}.model".format(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')) # saves only the best ones

# Train model
history = model.fit(
    train_x, train_y,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y),
    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],
)

# Score model
score = model.evaluate(validation_x, validation_y, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
# Save model
model.save("models/{}".format(NAME))
```

It throws the following CUPTI error

```
2019-12-28 20:31:45.798191: E tensorflow/core/platform/default/device_tracer.cc:70] CUPTI error: CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/Tutorial_codes/Deep Learning/crypto_rnn_tut.py", line 163, in <module>
    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint]
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Soni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 727, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Soni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 675, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Soni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 405, in model_iteration
    callbacks._call_batch_hook(mode, 'end', batch_index, batch_logs)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Soni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 236, in _call_batch_hook
    batch_hook(batch, logs)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Soni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 519, in on_train_batch_end
    self.on_batch_end(batch, logs=logs)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Soni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks_v1.py", line 362, in on_batch_end
    profiler.save(self.log_dir, profiler.stop())
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Soni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\profiler.py", line 140, in save
    gfile.MakeDirs(plugin_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Soni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 438, in recursive_create_dir
    recursive_create_dir_v2(dirname)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Soni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 453, in recursive_create_dir_v2
    pywrap_tensorflow.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.as_bytes(path))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: logs/60-SEQ-3-PRED-1577545294\plugins\profile\2019-12-28_20-31-45; No such file or directory
```

But when i delete the `callbacks` line from `model.fit` everything works great and model starts training.

I am new to Tensorflow so please tell me why i am not able to use tensorboard, do you need to have gpu to use the tensorboard?

Comment: The error is actually below of your CUPTI error, its better to include the full traceback.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro i have added the full traceback now in the edit, please check

Comment: So now the problem is clear: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: logs/60-SEQ-3-PRED-1577545294\plugins\profile\2019-12-28_20-31-45; No such file or directory You need to make sure that all folders except the last one exists, TensorBoard will only create the last folder in the path, the previous folders have to exist already

Comment: Can you tell me how to solve the problem i am pretty new to tensorflow and tensorboard.

Comment: I tried to delete that particular log also i tried to delete all log files but still i am getting the same error on both tries.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line before your tensorboard initialization line:

```
os.makedirs(f"logs\{NAME}", exist_ok=True)
```

You haven't made the folder yet to which tensorboard would log.